# "Не удается открыть источник файл GLFW\glfw3.h"

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

(Перед тем, как я расскажу о своей проблеме, на всякий случай оставлю ссылку на статью, с которой выполнял данные действия - https://ravesli.com/urok-2-podgotovka-k-pervomu-proektu-opengl-nastrojka-glfw-cmake-i-glad/)

Я установил GLFW с офф. сайта, установил CMake. Что делал дальше - думаю, объяснять не стоит, но я уже второй день не могу решить проблему. Фактически все файлы подключил к компилятору

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar6av.png]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никак не могу понять, в чем проблема

Comment: а что у вас в папке GLFW?

Comment: lib, include и glfw3.lib

Comment: Папку `...\glfw-3.3.2\include` не туда вписали, в "каталогах библиотек" она не нужна. Там где-то должен быть список папок, в которых ищутся заголовочные файлы, нужно добавить туда.

Comment: Не очень понимаю, что именно добавлять из папки glfw-3.3.2. У меня есть вроде все, вот только не могу ничего подключить

Comment: Я вам советую изучить основы С++, а затем уже переходить к такому зверю, как OpenGL

Comment: Спасибо, но я же недавно уже полностью прочитал книгу Лафоре, изучил многотопочность, немного QT. Без практики тоже не обошлось. Для меня всегда проблемой было именно начать. Когда я только начинал изучать C++, то были проблемы с файлами. А сейчас же проблемы с папками...

Comment: "Спасибо, но я же недавно уже полностью прочитал книгу Лафоре" И зачем было читать это старьё...
std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path) для папок. std::fstream для файлов. А я вообще советую не связываться с рендером опенжл директиус итд.

Comment: Здравствуй,(сори за вопрос, а не ответ), но у тебя получилось исправить ошибку?(тоже 2 дня уже потратил)

Comment: Получилось, но уже забил на это